# Reduce method not clear

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

So, I started playing with reduce() and I realised I can pass an Object as the first element of the method and I saw a couple of examples and this is one of them.

```
const arr = ['y', 'n', 'y', 'y', 'n'];

let test = arr2.reduce((sum, val) => {
    sum[val] = (sum[val] || 0) + 1;
    console.log('sum of val', sum[val], 'value', val)
    return sum;
}, {})
```

I added that console log so I can see what is going on, but I cant figure it out. HOW DOES THE METHOD KNOW? How does it add that val (which is n or y) in the object and followed by it add the sum of how many of identical elements exists in the array. How does that sum become for example {y: 20} - assuming there are 20 y's in an array.

Im confused by it, at first it seemed simple but I guess its not.

Comment: But when i console.log that sum[val] it gives me a value of the summed elements. So basically it means i said 0 = (0 || 0) + 1, where is that y or n then

Comment: See my answer below

Comment: Is this question about `.reduce()` or how `sum[val] = (sum[val] || 0) + 1` works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't "know", you *do* it, here: `sum[val] = (sum[val] || 0) + 1;`

`sum` is the empty object in the first iteration, and then it's the one returned from the previous iteration (which is the same, due to `return sum;`). And `val` is the current value (`'y'` or `'n'`).

So, in the first iteration, `sum` will be `{}` and `val` will be `'y'`. This line will then set `sum['y'] = 1` because it essentially does `sum['y'] = (sum['y'] || 0) + 1` - and `sum['y']` is `undefined` at that point, so you'll have `(undefined || 0) + 1` which is `0 + 1` which is `1`.

The next time the same happens for `'n'`.

And the third time, `sum['y']` will be already `1` from before, so that expression becomes `(1 || 0) + 1` which is `1 + 1` which is `2`, so you get `sum['y'] = 2`.

And so on.

See this screencast from a debugger: https://recordit.co/FVkXjW1b5y

Comment: So sum becomes an object (and permanently stays as an object) and that is why it works?

Comment: `sum` is from the start an object because you pass it to `.reduce()` (which is already in your question: _"I can pass an Object as the first element"_)

Comment: `x.reduce(..., {})` <== the `{}` here is the object! You pass it into the function yourself.

Answer (score 2):

`.reduce()` takes two arguments

- callback function
- initial value (optional)

In your case, empty object literal `{}` is the initial value. **If initial value is supplied, it is passed as the first argument to the callback function**.

Second argument to the callback function of `.reduce()` is the **current element of the array on which `.reduce()` is called**. In first iteration, `val` is the first element in the `arr` array, i.e. `'y'`.

```
sum[val] = (sum[val] || 0) + 1;
```

In each iteration, above statement will add value of `val` as a key in the `sum` object (initial value) and its value is `0 + 1` if `sum[val]` is undefined or `sum[val] + 1` if `sum[val]` is defined.

**How your code is executing:**

When callback is called for the first time, `sum` is `{}` and `val` is `'y'`. Since `sum[val]` or `sum['y']` is `undefined`, `'y'` is added as a key in `sum` and its value is 1. Same thing happens when callback function is called second time. After 2 calls, `sum` looks like `{ y: 1, n: 1 }`.

In third call, since `sum[val]` is equal to `1`, so previously added key `y` is overwritten with `sum[val] + 1` which evaluates to `1 + 1`. So after third call, `sum` looks like `{ y: 2, n: 1 }`. Same thing happens in the subsequent calls to callback function.